# Blender 2.78 Manual for offline use - how - where?

Tags: documentation

Blender Help says I can download the Blender 2.78 Manual for offline use - how - where?

Comment: blender (which I use, love and support since two decades...) has a terrible history of downloadable manuals... worst blender aspect ever, imho. when it was on mediawiki I started a project to regularly create a pdf version from it... then they switched to a version based on "reStructuredText " and although every project I've seen using this kind of system (see https://readthedocs.org/) has html, pdf, epub export at least... blender never had one. You could try to download manual sources and build it locally: see https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/about/contribute/index.html

Answer (score 7):

There is a link for the online documents here: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev . I'm not sure why it doesn't work, but there is a link to download a zip file, but the actually link tag isn't working in the wiki. For now, you can download directly, I guess: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/blender_manual.zip

Answer (score 2):

The `make.bat` file in the blender documentation subversion repository includes a "make epub" option that will use their tooling to build a local epub file locally. It's reasonably easy to do this same thing on Mac or Linux box if that's your platform.

A step-by-step of what I did was:

- `svn checkout https://svn.blender.org/svnroot/bf-manual/trunk/blender_docs`
- `cd blender_docs`
- `virtualenv .venv_blender`
- `source .venv_blender/bin/activate`
- `pip install -r requirements.txt`

and I added this to the local `Makefile`:

```
epub: .FORCE .SPHINXBUILD_EXISTS
    # './' (input), './epub/' (output)
    QUICKY_CHAPTERS=$(QUICKY_CHAPTERS) \
    $(SPHINXBUILD) -b epub $(SPHINXOPTS) ./manual "$(BUILDDIR)/epub"
```

Then `make epub` generates an epub file into `build/epub` directory.