# Using manual offline

Tags: documentation

Thank you. Once I made a copy of it all in a folder that was not related to My Documents, it works just fine. MY Documents would launch the index but take me to links in a temp directory which told me I needed to be online.

I open the index and genindex from blender.org and it launches Internet explorer. I can read the index page fine, but clicking on any sections tells me you're not connected to a network. In the address bar it shows a hard drive location. It won't open links to any sections unless I'm online

I can't get the manual to work on a pc without internet. It always launches a browser. I've downloaded the manual that says it's for offline use. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using the builtin help by right clicking directly from inside the Blender UI? I don't think the downloaded Blender manual is supposed to integrate with that functionality, as far as I know.

Comment: possible duplicate of: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/73311/blender-2-78-manual-for-offline-use-how-where

Answer (score 2):

If you downloaded a zip file from here: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/ , then you can open it with your browser but you don't need internet for display the pages. So you can read it offline.
You can see the web address in the browser's address bar is pointing to your harddrive, not web.

Comment: we can select the version on the combo left down, like https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.83/ that matches UPBGE0.3, thx!

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned already, the download for the manual contains html files and needs to be viewed in a web browser. While the page links are local to the download, there are some external links within the files.

There are several pages that have vimeo and youtube urls for example videos. These links should not do anything more than show previews as broken links and give you errors if you try and follow the links.

Many pages have two MathJax javascript files linked from cdnjs.cloudflare.com and one stylesheet from fonts.googleapi.com.

In my testing, the pages are viewable without an internet connection, I expect some functionality may fail with the missing js files, but the main files are readable.

The external js and css files should be copied locally for the offline copy. That is something that I [have reported](https://developer.blender.org/T53031) to the bugtracker to get fixed.